# Mapping a point into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, graphics, mapping, drawing

It's probably a simple question.

I want to get the numpy indices for a point with x,y Cartesian coordinates. Should I use `int()`, `floor()`, `ceil()`, or none of them?

The numpy array represents a gridmap and the (0,0) position of the Cartesian system should be at the center of the numpy array.

I found an image that kind of shows my question:

[image: screenshot showing desired mapping of coordinate to grid]

Comment: _Should I use int(), floor(), ceil(), or none of them?_ Are the coordinates floats? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes the Cartesian Coordinates are floats. The Grid can have a resolution for example 0.05 m per cell.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you're working in a 5x5 cartesian plane. You may decide to represent your plane in numpy like so:

```
>>> x = np.arange(-12,13)
>>> x.shape = (5,5)
>>> x
array([[-12, -11, -10,  -9,  -8],
       [ -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3],
       [ -2,  -1,   0,   1,   2],
       [  3,   4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11,  12]])
```

But your problem is your origin isn't located at (0,0):

```
>>> x[0,0]
-12
```

Because all arrays start at 0. To "fix" your index references, just offset your array indices by half of the 1D range whenever referencing your 2-dimensional array:

```
>>> x[math.floor(0 - 5/2),math.floor(0 - 5/2)]
0
```

Likewise:

```
>>> x[math.floor(-2 - 5/2),math.floor(-2 - 5/2)]
-12
```

And you could reference your array like so:

```
>>> for i in range(-2,3):
...     for j in range(-2,3):
...             ix = math.floor(i - 5/2)
...             jy = math.floor(j - 5/2)
...             x[ix,jy] = x[ix,jy] * 5
...             print("{0:>5}".format(x[ix,jy]),end="")
...     print()
...
  -60  -55  -50  -45  -40
  -35  -30  -25  -20  -15
  -10   -5    0    5   10
   15   20   25   30   35
   40   45   50   55   60
```

This is obviously a contrived example.

Comment: ok thanks. And if I use a resolution on the grid? for example 0.5 meters per cell. I just divide x,y by 0.5 and then subtract the offset and use floor right?

Comment: If you want each cell to represent 0.5 meters, then you would multiply by 0.5. e.g., 5 cells away from the origin on the x axis would be equivalent to 5*0.5 = 2.5 meters. If I understand your meaning correctly. For instance, the distance from the origin in meters if each cell equals 0.5 meters would be calculated with x[ix,jy] = math.sqrt((i*0.5)**2.0 + (j*0.5)**2.0)

Comment: I mean if i have a cartesian coordsystem 10 by 10 meters. And a numpy array with the Size 10/0.5x10/0.5 (0,5 resolution of grid). And now i want to map the point (2.3,-5.4) in meter into the grid. First i must divide 2.3 and -5.4 by 0.5 am i right?

Comment: I see. Yes, and then take the floor of that. Then each dimension would have 20 segments and your points would parsed into half meter buckets. So, (floor(2.3/0.5), floor(5.4/0.5)) = (4,10)